# Struggling with responsive banner

Tags: html, css

My website is www.onlinestaff.net

I posted a question previously about my website banner and got a solution with my glasslogo.png which I thank you for, but the banner as a whole seems it's not resizing when I make the screen smaller, ie the text and two buttons.

I don't know if I need to make the banner background an image instead of using a div for the image, because I need the banner as a whole with the image, text and buttons to get smaller to fit the page on tablets and mobile phones etc.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="thebanner">
    <h123>
        <span>A Free Admin,<br> Moderator, Freelancer & Writer Job Board.<br> <span class='spacer'></span>
    </h123>

    <buttonz>
        <span>
            <a href="http://onlinestaff.net/staff-required" class="Button1">Search for staff</a>
            <span class='spacer'></span>
    </buttonz>

    <buttonz2>
        <span>
            <a href="http://onlinestaff.net/work-required" class="Button1">
                Search for work
            </a>
            <span class='spacer'></span>
    </buttonz2>

    <div class="bannerimage" id="bannerimage">
        <img src="/glasslogo.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please adjust/format your HTML first, because above HTML doesn’t have proper opening and closing ‘tag’ and also share your CSS with us

Comment: <h123>, <buttonz>, <buttonz2>  are just the names to the divs i wanted to target so i gave them custom names, am i doing this wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that you have knowledge of Media queries in CSS. You can use media tags of specific screen sizes and on specific break points like in the below example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
body {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

}